# How To Send Request Header To Jetty WebSocket From JavaScript Client

Tags: java, javascript, saas, jetty-9, java-websocket

**How To Send Request Header To Jetty WebSocket From JavaScript Client ?**

---

### What I am doing ?

---

**At Client Side.**

1. Need To add service name and service version in request header at client side
2. Send to server

**At Server Side.**

1. Identify the service from the request header
2. Using that create corresponding input translator (using GSON)
3. Create service input using that translator
4. Call the service.

I can use org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket as to get service name and version at server side. But..... **How can I set the header information at client side?**

```
@OnWebSocketMessage
public void onText(Session session, String message) {
    if (session.isOpen()) {
        System.out.println(session.getUpgradeRequest().getHeader("service"));
        System.out.println(session.getUpgradeRequest().getHeader("version"));

        System.out.printf("Echoing back message [%s]%n", message);
        session.getRemote().sendString(message, null);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. The standard WebSocket JavaScript API does not provide means to customize HTTP headers. See also [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization) at heroku dev center.