# webrtc Socket connection via server authentication

Tags: java, android, sockets

Hi I am new to socket connection and I have test this application and its working .
Normally we use host and port to do socket connection .
Now I have host and port with server credential .
A webrtc is working on web and websocket connection is using following format if Please tell me how to pass user credential while making connection then please let me know . 
Following url is used in websocket in JS

```
url = host+port
function connect(url, me, password)
{

  var protocol = window.location.protocol == "http:" ? "ws" : "wss";
  ws = new WebSocket(protocol + "://" + url +"/ws/server?username="+ me +"&password=" + password + "&resource=" + me, "xmpp");
  ws.onopen = onOpen;
  ws.onmessage = onMessage;
  ws.onclose = onConnectionClose;  
}
```

Comment: Hmm...why going with Websocket when you can use httprequest or Volley...?Personally,I preffer the httprequest because I haven't bothered trying to understand Volley, but as far as I know,Volley rocks.

Comment: Websocket is used on web.  I am using socket connection in android and ... may question is that how can we make socket connection via credential ... and thanks for reply ..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29854983/1174054 The standard WebSocket JavaScript API does not provide means to customize HTTP headers. That is, you cannot add `Authorization` header. However, in a native Java application, you can add credentials in a WebSocket request.